# Multithread array threadsafe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have code like this, some threads will generate string (here 100) and store to array, other single thread will read data using indexer [] and save to file. I used Interlocked class for string swapping in ThreadSafeString class but I don't know if its enough to avoid deadlocks and non thread safe problems. Other idea I have is to use `ConcurrentDirectory<int, string>` to be sure its safe.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test
{
    class ThreadSafeString
    {
        private string _string;

        public string Value
        {
            get => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _string, null, null);
            set => Interlocked.Exchange(ref _string, value);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ThreadSafeString[] array = new ThreadSafeString[100];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) array[i] = new ThreadSafeString();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string data = "";
                        //generate data

                        array[i].Value = data;
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                });
                thread.Name = i.ToString();
                thread.Start();
            }

            var ht = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        string temp = array[i].Value;
                        File.WriteAllText(path, temp);
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            });
            ht.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you doing this is this an exercise for school? otherwise use the Concurrent Collections built into .Net

Comment: Sounds like a job for... anything else. Parallel LINQ (`Enumerable.AsParallel()`), the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), `Parallel.For[Each]`, `Task`s, take your pick. Manually gathering results from parallel computations is something you ideally should not want to bother with yourself.

Comment: I would like use Concurrent Collections but only Dictionary is key based, ideally I need something like list or array.

Comment: And its not for school, I have app that multithreads are doing job and need collection for insterting snapchots (strings) to know what was last task did by thread. Single thread are saving this to file, so after crash I can start where it stopped.

Comment: @3v0 [thread-safe list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Can you drop the thread writing to the file? Or have one file per thread? Seems like having the process being executed on the thread output it's own status into it's own file would be a much simpler solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a point in ThreadSafeString here. Use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` if you need to compare, store and return old data as a single operation.

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _string, null, null);
```

means

```
if (_string == null)
{
    _string = null;
    return null;
} else return _string;
```

but as a single operation. As you can see it can be easily replaced with

```
return __string;
```

same with `Interlocked.Exchange` - you don't need to do it for strings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#atomicity-of-variable-references

> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char,
>   byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types.

You need to do it only for types other than that and if you need to get old value as an atomic operation.
Simply using `string[]` here will have same thread-safety. You can safely store and read data from array as long as you don't change array size and operate on reference types or single word sized value types. You only need to worry about thread-safety if you want to read, change and store data back, but this is another problem that is not even solved by collections like `ConcurrentDirectory`

Comment: Good point, but other question is string[] good for multithread save and read. I wont modify string after generating, I only need to transfer them to 1 thread for saving.

Comment: sure it is. This is how all of these thread-safe collections work underneath. The only thing they do is they version arrays and regulates access to them

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
To reflect your comment I changed to the use of `ConcurrentDictionary`.

The dictionary will take care for the threadsafe reading and writing of the strings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> threadResults = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string data = i.ToString();
                        threadResults.AddOrUpdate(i, data, (id, x) => data);
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }).Start();
            }

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    foreach (var threadResult in threadResults)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{threadResult.Key} {threadResult.Value}");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine("press return to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but I need only the most recent data from threads, eg one will process data in 200ms and second in 1000ms, saving to by 2s in queue there will be 10 strings from thread1 and 2 from thread2 (need only 1 from thread1 and 1 from thread2). I dont want to decrease saving delay for disc performance.

Comment: @3v0 i updated my answer to reflect your comment. Hope I got you right.

Comment: Thanks, thats wokring!